# Stuck in a Review Account loop

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id, mac-appstore, accounts

I just got my first iPhone and created my Apple ID. I tried to download some apps from the AppStore, but it keeps telling me

> this Apple ID has not been used yet, please review account to continue

and asks for password, but then goes nowhere. It just keeps bringing me back to requesting the password over and over.

I have tried to put in billing/shipping info in settings to no avail. Unfortunately I don’t have a Mac, nor do I have a computer that has iTunes  on it so I can't log in there.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome on AskDifferent. Please have a look at the tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour. I am not 100% sure but it sounds like you have not confirmed your account via mail. Did you follow all the steps provided here: https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT204316? Tell us exactly what you have done, e.g. followed this tutorial: https://www.igeeksblog.com/apple-id-has-not-been-used-in-the-itunes/? Also I have edited your post to only include the necessary info. Also, if you just bought it 5 days ago, why not call Apple support, email or chat: https://support.apple.com/en-hk

Answer (score 13):

Solution which worked for me:

1. Open Music app
2. Sign-in with Apple ID
3. Accept agreement which would not initiate in appstore.
4. Open AppStore & sign in with same Apple ID.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

It may be late but could be useful for someone else.

So, I just faced the same issue where I was being asked to Review the iTunes account in a loop.

The solution is to open your AppStore > click on your Profile Icon from the top right corner > and complete the review process there.

Comment: That did not work for me, but the solution by user979016, signing in through the music app, did work.

Answer (score 0):

This was highly frustrating. For newer Macs (like 2021 and after), they don't have iTunes (now Apple Music) and there is no profile icon on the App Store. The way I got out of it was to open Apple TV icon, then check the checkbox "accept terms and conditions" then putting in a payment method.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to go anywhere, guys. Here is the solution:

1. Go to Setting of iPhone
2. Open your profile
3. Go to Media & Purchases
4. Delete the existing account
5. Sign In with your iCloud account.

toggle the term & condition button once asked